# Django not able to locate static files

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

i am frustrated now ..been trying this for 2 days now.. tried every thing Django is not importing static files

**My settings**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'my_blog'/'static',

]
```

**my imports**

```
 href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}"
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
  />
    <link
      href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
   

    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

      <link
      href="{% static 'base.css' %}"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
```

Comment: In your hierachy of directories, where is located `js/...` and `css/...` ?

Comment: 1. did you run collectstatic?
2. did you insert {% load static %} at template file?
your directory structure would help.

Comment: jss and css are in static root directory  mean (`blog/static/css , blog/static/js`) like this @SergioC, while as `base.css` is in my app directory e.g `my_blog/static/base.css` base file is working fine

Comment: I did use load static, and I believe collect static is used at the time of deployment

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py` file keep these such way:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'static'

....
....

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

Now create a folder named `static` and keep all static files there.

if the file structure is such that:

`-static`

`--css`

`---style.css`

then your `src or href` would be such `{% static 'css/style.css' %}`